# Shiny Server wont load app

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I am having an incredibly difficult time getting my Shiny app to run in Shiny Server (on Ubuntu 16.04). I followed the instructions on R-Studio's website installing R and Shiny Server on Ubuntu. Running the status command shows that shiny server is running.

[image]

My shiny app (which works fine on my windows machine) is found in the /srv/shiny-server/HealthCheck directory.

I am trying to run this locally (not hosting on an outside web server etc), I have tried many different ways to access the app, but all have failed with either "page not found" errors or "could not connect to.." errors. I have tried accessing the app through these methods in Firefox:

http://localhost:3838/srv/shiny-server/HealthCheck

http://ipaddress:3838/srv/shiny-server/HealthCheck

http://localhost:3838/HealthCheck

http://ipaddress:3838/HealthCheck

I have tried different ports, adding and removing server_name to config file. I have tried turning on logging but nothing ever writes to the /var/log/shiny-server folder, making this hard to troubleshoot.

Any help would be greatly apprecitated. I assume i am making some simple mistake here, but cant seem to figure this one out.  Here is my shiny config file:

```
run_as shiny;

# Define a server that listens on port 3838
server {
      listen 3838;
    server_name localhost;

    location /HealthCheck {
     app_dir /srv/shiny-server/HealthCheck;
    log_dir /var/log/shiny-server;
     simple_scheduler 15;
        }
}

preserve_logs true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out for anyone else who has a similar issue. Specifying the port alone wasn't enough when running as localhost. I also specified the localhost IP and then it worked.

```
listen 3838 127.0.0.1;
```

Comment: having this same problem on azure. No logs, no real error message. Can you expand on what you mean? In the config?